# Use Variable Height Images and set highest item height to GridView Container in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on an UWP application with GridView with variable height images. I am showing images using `ContainerContentChanging` event. So program will load only text information first and then it will load images.

**ISSUE:**

It sets height of item container same as the height of the first images.

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

It should set height of container same as the highest image height.

**CODE:**

```
<ListView ContainerContentChanging="GridView_ContainerContentChanging" SelectionChanged="GridView_SelectionChanged">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
            <Grid CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Click="Button_Click" GotFocus="Button_GotFocus"
                        LostFocus="Button_LostFocus" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="116"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Background="Transparent">
                    <RelativePanel CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" Background="Transparent">
                        
                        <Border
                        Background="Transparent"
                        CornerRadius="4,4,4,4"
                        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                        RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True"
                        Visibility="Visible">
                            <TextBlock
                            x:Name="TextTitleEmpty"
                            Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                            Text="{x:Bind Title}"
                            TextAlignment="center" 
                            FontSize="10"
                            Padding="10,0,10,0"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Image
                        x:Name="ItemImage"
                        Width="116"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                        Stretch="Uniform" />

                        <Border
                        Background="#BF000000"
                        RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                        Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBlock
                            x:Name="TextTitle"
                            Padding="0,0,0,1"
                            MaxLines="2"
                            Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                            Text="{x:Bind Title}"
                            FontSize="10"
                            Foreground="White"
                            TextAlignment="center"
                            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </Border>
                    </RelativePanel>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="116" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,4,4,14" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,4,4,4" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                <ListViewItemPresenter
                                CornerRadius="4,4,4,4"
                                SelectedBackground="Transparent"
                                SelectedPointerOverBackground="Transparent"
                                PressedBackground="Transparent"
                                SelectedPressedBackground="Transparent" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Margin="23,60,0,40" Orientation="Horizontal"
                                   BringIntoViewRequested="ItemsWrapGrid_BringIntoViewRequested"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>


private void GridView_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.InRecycleQueue)
            {
                var templateRoot = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as FrameworkElement;
                var image = (Image)templateRoot.FindName("ItemImage");

                image.Source = null;
                image.Opacity = 0;
                args.Handled = true;
            }

            if (args.Phase == 0)
            {
                var templateRoot = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as FrameworkElement;
                var image = (Image)templateRoot.FindName("ItemImage");
                image.Source = null;
                image.Opacity = 0;

                args.RegisterUpdateCallback(ShowImage);
                args.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private async void ShowImage(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Phase == 1)
            {
                var item = args.Item as ListItem;
                var bitmapImage = await item.GetImageThumbnailAsync();

                //Trace.TraceInformation("ShowImage " + item.game.BoxFrontFileName);

                // It's phase 1, so show this item's image.
                var templateRoot = args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot as FrameworkElement;
                var image = (Image)templateRoot.FindName("ItemImage");

                image.Opacity = 0;
                image.Source = bitmapImage;
                if (image.Source == null)
                {
                    bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(image.BaseUri, "Assets/empty.png");
                    image.Source = bitmapImage;
                }
                
                image.Opacity = 100;
                args.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

**NOTE:**

The "ContainerContentChanging" event used for this extension to work, will not be raised when the ItemsPanel is replaced with another type of panel than ItemsStackPanel or ItemsWrapGrid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems that you are using a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview?view=winrt-22621) not a [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview?view=winrt-22621). The solution for this is to create a custom panel for which will adjust the height based on different items.

```
public class GridViewCustomPanel : Panel
{
private double maxWidth;
private double maxHeight;

protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
    var x = 0.0;
    var y = 0.0;
    foreach (var child in Children)
    {
        if ((maxWidth + x) > finalSize.Width)
        {
            x = 0;
            y += maxHeight;
        }
        var newpos = new Rect(x, y, maxWidth, maxHeight);
        child.Arrange(newpos);
        x += maxWidth;
    }
    return finalSize;
}

protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    foreach (var child in Children)
    {
        child.Measure(availableSize);

        var desirtedwidth = child.DesiredSize.Width;
        if (desirtedwidth > maxWidth)
            maxWidth = desirtedwidth;

        var desiredheight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
        if (desiredheight > maxHeight)
            maxHeight = desiredheight;
    }
    var itemperrow = Math.Floor(availableSize.Width / maxWidth);
    var rows = Math.Ceiling(Children.Count / itemperrow);
    return new Size(itemperrow * maxWidth, maxHeight * rows);
}
```

}

You could ask check Fay's answer here:
[GridView in GridView UWP Height Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60251708/gridview-in-gridview-uwp-height-issue)

Comment: This is the biggest limitation -
The "ContainerContentChanging" event used for this extension to work, will not be raised when the ItemsPanel is replaced with another type of panel than ItemsStackPanel or ItemsWrapGrid.  I already tried this. Its not working.

Comment: @GaurangDave There are no other solutions for this. I'd suggest you use binding to show the image instead of setting the source manually

Comment: That is the problem here. I am loading lots of images.  If you have seen C# code, there is a method which load bitmap. I load it them from stream not file path. By the way, this is a XBOX app. app will be slow down if I load all images using binding because item source will be preloaded.  DO you think any other way?

Comment: @GaurangDave Just load parts of it first. Not load them all.

Comment: ok I will try that. Just asking this - is there any way I can override current Panel's arrange and Measure events?  ---- I want to try all possible options in the current implementation before I make a major change.

Comment: @GaurangDave I'm afraid no. You have to create a custom panel to override this. Besides, it is possible to get images with same size?

Comment: Its not possible to get the same size images. It will be variable size.